# How to represent the following set operation.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

Suppose that $A=\{(a,b)\mid a \in C, b\in D\}$ is a set of ordered pairs; and $E \subset C$. If I want to select the ordered pairs in which the first element $a \in E$ from the set $A$, how to represent it mathematically? Can I write it as
$$\{(a,b)\in A\mid a \in E\}?$$

Comment: Yes, that works!

Comment: Did you mean to have $b \in D$ instead of $B \in D$?

Comment: $E \times D$ is also a possibility, but it doesnt show the fact that it's a subset of $A$

Comment: @David Yes, it should be $b \in D$. I have corrected it.

Comment: You could write it that way.  Or you could write it as $\{(a,b)|a\in E, b\in D\}$.  Or as $E \times D$ (and $A = C\times D$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $A$ is really just $C\times D$, in which case the set you are looking for is $E\times D$.

If $A$ is really just an arbitrary subset of $C\times D$, e.g. a function $f\colon C\to D$, then you can write $A\restriction E$ to mean $\{(a,b)\in A\mid a\in E\}$.

Just be sure to explain precisely what you mean when you write $A\restriction E$, to avoid any possible confusion for the readers.